# Presence of jQuery-UI breaks d3.js code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, d3.js

The following code breaks if one uncomments the commented-out line (jsFiddles: [OK](http://jsfiddle.net/VWa8m/) and [broken](http://jsfiddle.net/j2N2k/)):

```
<div style="width:150px;height:50px;padding:20px;color:white;"></div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> -->
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
(function ($) {
  "use strict";
   $('div').css('background-color', d3.rgb(192, 0, 0))
           .text('jQuery version: ' + $().jquery);
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

(Just to be clear, in the "broken" version, the `background-color` is set to black, rather than the color specified.)

In my book, this is a bug in jQuery-UI: loading a library should not just break pre-existing code like this.  (It took me *a very long time* to debug it!)

But I have little experience with jQuery-UI, and maybe I'm grossly misusing it.

Is there a more correct way to import jQuery-UI that would prevent this sort of problem?

BTW: I know how to fix the problem shown in the example above (e.g. replace `d3.rgb(192, 0, 0)` with `#c00`); that's not my question.

Comment: It works if you do `d3.rgb(...).toString()`, which you should probably do anyway. I know that this is not your question, but I'm guessing that jquery ui somehow modifies how this function is evaluated.

Comment: Oh and +1 for providing a minimal example and not dumping all your code indiscriminately :)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: as it turns out, adding `.toString()` is how I actually fixed the problem when I narrowed it down enough.